# Cython error: C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a: error adding symbols

Tags: installation, cython

I'm doing my first test with Cython. Basically the `hello.pyx` example from http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html

When I want to compile I get the following error:

```
C:[...]>python setup.py build_ext --inplace
Compiling hello.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing hello.pyx
running build_ext
building 'hello' extension
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c he
llo.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\hello.o
writing build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\hello.def
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\hello.o build\temp.
win32-2.7\Release\hello.def -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27\PCbuild -lpython27
-lmsvcr90 -o C:\Users\Bernd\Documents\99_Projekte\ONGOING\201412_Laufauswertung\
Repro\Tests\hello.pyd
C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a: error adding symbols: File format not recognized

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

The file `hello.c` is generated.

Any idea?

**Edit 1:**

Following the hint from J.J. Hakala, i did the following: move `libpython27.a` away from `C:\Python27\libs` (for example bak subdirectory), and copy `python27.dll` from `c:\windows\system32 to c:\python27\libs`

Now the result is:

```
C:[...]>python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
building 'hello' extension
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c he
llo.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\hello.o
writing build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\hello.def
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\hello.o build\temp.
win32-2.7\Release\hello.def -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27\PCbuild -lpython27
-lmsvcr90 -o C:\Users\Bernd\Documents\99_Projekte\ONGOING\201412_Laufauswertung\
Repro\Tests\hello.pyd
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x2d9): undefined reference
to `_imp___PyThreadState_Current'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x3b3): undefined reference
to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x444): undefined reference
to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x8e1): undefined reference
to `_imp__PyExc_ImportError'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

A folder `build\temp.win32-2.7\Release` with the files `hello.def` and `hello.o` is generated.

**Edit 2:**
Maybe the solution is here: [compiling Cython with MinGW - undefined reference PyExc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440789/compiling-cython-with-mingw-undefined-reference-pyexc)

I'll try to install Visual Studio and then try again. Recommendation on how to make it run on MinGW are still wellcome.

Comment: You could test the following: move `libpython27.a`  away from C:\Python27\libs (for example bak subdirectory), and copy `python27.dll` from c:\windows\system32 to c:\python27\libs

Comment: Thank you for that hint J J Hakala. I have the feeling we made some progress, althroug still not working. See edit for details.

Comment: Does adding `-mthreads` when compiling improve the situation? I noticed that I have that flag in my cython-related Makefile.

Comment: `python setup.py build_ext --inplace -mthreads` did deliver `Option -m not recognised`.   I'm not trying to install `dlltool` and `gendef`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If tools *gendef* and *dlltool* are installed, the following should be possible in a temporary directory (assuming msys or cygwin environment):

```
gendef c:/Windows/System32/python27.dll
dlltool -U -d python27.def -l libpython27.dll.a
cp libpython27.dll.a c:/Python27/libs
```

Substitute *C:/Python27* if necessary.

gcc will now use the generated file instead of some existing `.a` or `.lib` file.

Comment: Great News: after doing this `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` runs through w/o any error. An Folder `release`is generated with `*.gen *.o *.pyd` files. I'm only confused since i don't find an `*.exe` file. So where do i find an Windows executable? (Sorry if i have some misunderstanding here)

Comment: @BerndGit you have built a python extension module, not a standalone executable. When you do `import hello`, the classes and functions provided by the extension module will be available.

Comment: Ok thanks. I found answers to my follow up questions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581784/can-cython-compile-to-an-exe