# Error linking python lib with swig and g++

Tags: python, c++, g++, mingw, swig

I try the compilation of a wrapper of c++ code in python 2.7 with SWIG. (Please correct my formulation if wrong). This code uses to work on another machine, and all libraries (especially -lpython27) stand where they should be,

PATH variables include (among others) : "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python27\libs;C:\Python27;C:\MinGW\bin"

PYTHONPATH includes : C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages

I compile with :

```
swig.exe -c++ -python test8.i
g++.exe  -c -Wall test8.cpp 
g++.exe  -c -Wall test8_wrap.cxx -I C:\Python27\include -I C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\ 2> log_file2.txt
g++.exe  -Wall -shared -I C:\Python27\include -I C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\ -L C:\Python27\libs\ -lpython27 test8.o test8_wrap.o -o _Amod.pyd 2> log_file3.txt
```

I think the 3 first lines compile correctly, because I got test8.o and test8_wrap.o as output. But the last line fails to output the library _Amod.pyd and I get the error :

```
g++.exe : test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x8fd): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_AsString'
Au niveau de C:\Users\mollica\Documents\Python\Py_Proj\test8_spy\compile_swig_script8_win.ps1 : 5 Caractère : 8
+ g++.exe <<<<   -Wall -shared -I C:\Python27\include -I C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\ -L C:\Python
27\libs\ -lpython27 test8.o test8_wrap.o -o _Amod.pyd 2> log_file3.txt
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (test8_wrap.o:te...tring_AsString':String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x912): undefined reference to
 `_imp__PyString_FromString'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x940): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_MemoryError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x94f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_IOError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x95b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x967): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_IndexError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x973): undefined reference
 to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x97f): undefined reference
 to `_imp__PyExc_ZeroDivisionError'
test8_wrap.o
:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x98b): undefined reference to
 `_imp__PyExc_OverflowError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx
:(.text+0x997): undefined
 reference to `_imp__PyExc_SyntaxError
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text
+0x9a3): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ValueError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x9af): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_SystemError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x9bb): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_AttributeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x9c7): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x9f1): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xa15): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Fetch'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xa2d): undefined
 reference to `_imp__PyObject_Str'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xa37): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Clear'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xa79): undefined
 reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx
:(.text+0xad6): undefined
 reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text
+0xae7): undefined reference
 to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
test8_wrap.o
:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xb0d): undefined
 reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetObject
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xb55): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xb78): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_SetItemString'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xbc4): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xc24): undefined reference to `_imp__PyList_New'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text
+0xc43): undefined reference to
 `_imp__PyList_SetItem'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx
:(.text+0xc57): undefined
 reference to `_imp__PyList_Append
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text
+0xcc5): undefined reference to
 `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx
:(.text+0xce9): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xd54): undefined reference
 to `_imp__PyExc_SystemError'
test8_wrap.o
:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xd66
): undefined reference to
 `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx
:(.text+0xd9c): undefined
 reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
test8_wrap.o
:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xdc7): undefined reference to
 `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx
:(.text+0xdf4): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xe1f): undefined reference
 to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx
:(.text+0xe96): undefined
 reference to `_imp__Py_BuildValue
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xfa0): undefined reference to `_imp__PyClass_Type'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xfde): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttrString'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x100b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_New'
test8_wrap.o
:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1032
): undefined reference to
 `_imp__PyTuple_SetItem'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx
:(.text+0x1061): undefined
 reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttrString'
test8_wrap.o
:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1070): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text
+0x1080): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Clear'
test8_wrap.o
:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x11b2
): undefined reference to
 `_imp__PyLong_FromVoidPtr
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x11cf): undefined reference
 to `_imp__PyTuple_New'
test8_wrap.o
:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1200
): undefined reference to
 `_imp__PyTuple_SetItem'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx
:(.text+0x1235): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_Format
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x130d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_FromFormat'
test8_wrap.o
:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x133f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_ConcatAndDel
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x139a): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NotImplementedStruct'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx
:(.text+0x13a4): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NotImplementedStruct
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text
+0x13ab): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NotImplementedStruct'
test8_wrap.o
:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x13e5): undefined reference to
 `_imp__PyBool_FromLong'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x154e): undefined
 reference to `_imp__PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text
+0x1650): undefined reference
 to `_imp__PyObject_Free'
test8_wrap.o
:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x173b
): undefined reference to
 `_imp__PyArg_UnpackTuple'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text
+0x1761): undefined reference
 to `_imp__PyBool_FromLong'
test8_wrap.o
:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1778
): undefined reference to
 `_imp__PyObject_IsTrue'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx
:(.text+0x17fb): undefined reference to `_imp__PyType_Ready
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text
+0x1839): undefined reference
 to `_imp__PyObject_Malloc'
test8_wrap.o
:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1847
): undefined reference to
 `_imp__PyObject_Init'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx
:(.text+0x19b6): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_FromFormat
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x19d2
): undefined reference to
 `_imp__PyString_FromFormat'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx
:(.text+0x1a3c): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_FromFormat
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text
+0x1bb3): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_Free'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1c39): undefined
 reference to `_imp__PyObject_GenericGetAttr
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1c81): undefined reference
 to `_imp__PyType_Ready'
test8_wrap.o
:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1cbf): undefined reference to
 `_imp__PyObject_Malloc'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1ccd): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_Init
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1d2d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_Free'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx
:(.text+0x1e04): undefined reference to `_imp__PyInstance_Type'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1e1c
): undefined reference to `_imp___PyInstance_Lookup
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1e31): undefined reference
 to `_imp___PyObject_GetDictPtr'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1e5e
): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_GetItem
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1e7a): undefined reference
 to `_imp___PyWeakref_ProxyType'
test8_wrap.o
:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1e89
): undefined reference to
 `_imp___PyWeakref_CallableProxyType'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx
:(.text+0x1edd): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttr
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1f1b): undefined reference
 to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
test8_wrap.o
:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1f2b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Clear'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x21c7): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x21db): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x21eb): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Clear'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x22d2): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x22e2): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Clear'
test8_wrap.o
:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2301): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCFunction_Type'
test8_wrap.o
:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x24d1): undefined
 reference to `_imp__PyObject_Call
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text
+0x24e7): undefined reference to
 `_imp___PyObject_GetDictPtr'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx
:(.text
+0x2505
): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_New'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx
:(.text+0x252f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_SetItem
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2538): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_New
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2560): undefined reference
 to `_imp__PyDict_SetItem'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx
:(.text+0x2577): undefined
 reference to `_imp__PyInstance_NewRaw
'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x25be): undefined reference to `_imp___PyObject_GetDictPtr'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x25dc): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_New'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2606): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_SetItem'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x261d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttrString'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x263f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_SetItem'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x27ad): undefined reference to `_imp___PyObject_New'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x28e4): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCapsule_Import'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x28f0): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2900): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Clear'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x292d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCapsule_GetPointer'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x29f8): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_InitModule4'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2a18): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCapsule_New'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2a43): undefined reference to `_imp__PyModule_AddObject'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2aae): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_New'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2b1b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_GetItem'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2b39): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCapsule_GetPointer'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2b8f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCapsule_New'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2bad): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_SetItem'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2c17): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2c54): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Fetch'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2c6c): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_Str'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2c87): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Clear'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2cbe): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2cf1): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2d3d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2d6d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyOS_snprintf'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2dcc): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_Str'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2df7): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2e1e): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2e27): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2e47): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2e84): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2e9d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2ea6): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2eb8): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2ef9): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Clear'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2f12): undefined reference to `_imp__PyImport_ImportModule'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2f29): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ImportError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2f3b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2f5a): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttrString'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2f96): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_AttributeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2fa8): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2fbf): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCObject_Type'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2fc8): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2fda): undefined reference
 to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x301d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCObject_AsVoidPtr'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x305e): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3070): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x30a1): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x30bf): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x30f8): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3116): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x313b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x314d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3161): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3173): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3196): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ValueError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x31b6): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x322b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCallable_Check'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3283): undefined reference to `_imp__PyFloat_Type'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3293): undefined reference to `_imp__PyFloat_Type'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x329f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyType_IsSubtype'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x331e): undefined reference to
 `_imp__PyFile_Type'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x332e): undefined reference to `_imp__PyFile_Type'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x333a): undefined reference to `_imp__PyType_IsSubtype'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3362): undefined reference to `_imp__PyModule_Type'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3372): undefined reference to `_imp__PyModule_Type'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x337e): undefined reference to `_imp__PyType_IsSubtype'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x33a6): undefined reference to `_imp__PyInstance_Type'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x343f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyType_IsSubtype'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x34c3): undefined reference to `_imp__PyType_IsSubtype'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3500): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3520): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x354c): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x356c): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x35be): undefined reference to `_imp__PyType_IsSubtype'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3927): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3939): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3967): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3979): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x39aa): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x39c7): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3b12): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3b32): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3d39): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3d5f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3e41): undefined reference to `_imp__PyFloat_Type'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3e51): undefined reference to `_imp__PyFloat_Type'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3e5d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyType_IsSubtype'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3e84): undefined reference to `_imp__PyFloat_AsDouble'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3eb8): undefined reference to `_imp__PyInt_AsLong'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3ee9): undefined reference to `_imp__PyLong_AsDouble'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3ef3): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3f18): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Clear'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3f48): undefined reference to `_imp__PyInt_AsLong'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3f75): undefined reference to `_imp__PyLong_AsLong'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3f7f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3fa4): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Clear'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x3ffc): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ValueError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x402a): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x40a5): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ValueError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x40d3): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x4135): undefined reference to `_imp__PyBool_Type'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x414b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_IsTrue'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x4191): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ValueError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x41b8): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x42a7): undefined reference to `_imp__PyArg_ParseTuple'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x4534): undefined reference to `_imp__P
yErr_Occurred'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x460b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyArg_ParseTuple'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x48ed): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x4a25): undefined reference to `_imp__PyArg_ParseTuple'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x4dc9): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x4e73): undefined reference to `_imp__PyArg_ParseTuple'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x51a5): undefined reference to `_imp__PyArg_ParseTuple'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x5573): undefined reference to `_imp__PyArg_ParseTuple'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x5888): undefined reference to `_imp__PyArg_ParseTuple'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x5957): undefined reference to `_imp__PyArg_ParseTuple'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x5d5d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_FromString'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x5d73): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_FromString'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x5d90): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_FromString'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x5da1): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_ConcatAndDel'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x5db9): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_FromString'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x5dca): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_ConcatAndDel'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x5de7): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_FromString'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x5df8): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_ConcatAndDel'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x5f28): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x5f43): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_AttributeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x5f5c): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x5fc0): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x5fdb): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_AttributeError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x5ff4): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x60ba): undefined reference to `_imp__PyType_Ready'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x60f8): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_Malloc'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text
+0x6106): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_Init'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x62cd): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_SetItemString'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x6597): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_InitModule4'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x65a7): undefined reference to `_imp__PyModule_GetDict'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x65e2): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Print'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x65e9): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ImportError'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x65fb): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
test8_wrap.o:test8_wrap.cxx:(.data+0xc8): undefined reference to `PyObject_GenericGetAttr
'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

By looking around it seems that these errors come from the bad linking of -lpython27. But in my case, it's correctly included so I don't see where do I miss something. 64bits vs 32bits problem ? how can I check that ?

Kind regards,

F.M.

Comment: You could try generating `libpython27.dll.a` following the instructions in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34934865/5781248)

Answer (score 1):

Move the `-lpython27` after the `.o` files on the last compile line. The python27 library is loaded and then no dependencies are required because the `.o` files have not been looked at, so the symbols are not retained. See [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Comment: Are you able to share a sample of your .cpp code so I can try to compile on my machine?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I must build a simple "hello world" (or "hello numpy array" here) example first. I come back to the forum after.